# Link (on a while loop on a search query) inside a search form

Tags: php

```
echo "<center><form name = 'searching' method='POST' action='cpanel.php?manage=".$useraccounts."&rcad=".$viewcustomer."'><table border = 1>";
        echo "<select name = 'filter'>";
        echo "<option value ='username'>Username</option>";
        echo "<option value ='username'>Username</option>";
        echo "</select>";
        echo "  <input name='search' type='text' >   "; 
        echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Search'> ";
        echo "<input type='submit' name='back' value='Back'><br><br>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>User ID</td>";
        echo "<td>Username</td>";
        echo "<td>Last Name</td>";
        echo "<td>First Name</td>";
        echo "<td>Middle Initial</td>";
        echo "<td>Address</td>";
        echo "<td>Contact Number</td>";
        echo "<td>Birthday</td>";
        echo "<td>Date Registered</td>"; 
        echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        $submit = $_POST['submit'];
        if(isset($submit)) {
        $search = $_POST['search'];
        $filter = $_POST['filter'];

            include "dbconnect.php";
            if ($search != NULL) {
            $searchquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM register WHERE $filter LIKE '%$search%'");
            while($fetchres = mysql_fetch_array($searchquery)) { //show search results

            $userid = $fetchres['userid'];
            $username = $fetchres['username'];
            $lname = $fetchres['lname'];
            $fname = $fetchres['fname'];
            $mi = $fetchres['mi'];
            $address = $fetchres['address'];
            $contact = $fetchres['contact'];
            $month = $fetchres['month'];
            $day = $fetchres['day'];
            $year = $fetchres['year'];
            $dateregistered = $fetchres['date'];
            $sendmessage = "<a href = 'cpanel.php?manage=".$useraccounts."&rcad=".$viewcustomer."&user=".$username."'>Send message</a>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$userid</td>";
            echo "<td>$username</td>";
            echo "<td>$lname</td>";
            echo "<td>$fname</td>";
            echo "<td>$mi</td>";
            echo "<td>$address</td>";
            echo "<td>$contact</td>";
            echo "<td>$month $day, $year</td>";
            echo "<td>$dateregistered</td>";
            echo "<td>$sendmessage</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "$table";

            if (isset($sendmessage)) {
                $getuser = $_GET['user'];
                if ($getuser == $username) {
                //start send message
                $touser = $username;
                $fromuser = $adminsess;
                $subject = $_POST['subject'];
                $message = $_POST['message'];
                $submit = $_POST['submit'];
                $date = date("Y-m-d"); 
                $rand = rand(98765432,23456789);

                $table = '<center><script type="text/javascript" src="/js/sendmessage.js"></script>
                <form action="cpanel.php?manage='.$useraccounts.'&rcad='.$viewcustomer.'&user='.$username.'&send='.$one.'"  method="post" name="sendpm" onsubmit="return valid()">
                <table>
                <tr>
                <td>
                To:
                </td>
                <td>
                '.$touser.'
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>
                Subject:
                </td>
                <td>
                <input type="text" name="subject" id="subj1" />
                </td>
                </tr>    
                <tr>
                <td>
                Message:
                </td>
                <td>
                <textarea name="message" cols="60" rows="10" id="mes1"></textarea>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" name = "submit" value="Submit" />
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                </form></center>';
                        if (isset($submit))
                        {

                            $send = $_GET['send'];
                            if ($send == $one) {


                            include "maildbconnect.php";
                            $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO mailtbl_admin VALUES ('', '$touser', '$fromuser', '$subject',
                            '$message', '0', '0', '1', '$date', '$rand')");
                            echo "Message successfully sent."; 
                            } 
                        }
                }//end send message
            }//end $getuser


            }

        }
```

The form for sending a message ($table) doesn't appear after clicking the link ($sendmessage) on a certain search result. After clicking the link, i'm prompted to an empty table (table not inside the while loop) but the $_GET function is working. Can anyone tell me how to fix this? thanks a lot

Comment: I suspect you should replace `if (isset($sendmessage))` with `if (isset($_GET['user']))`.  `$sendmessage` is always going to be set - you just initialized it ~10 lines prior.

Comment: Thanks for that one mate, but after changing it to (isset($_GET['user'])), it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

$submit wont be set when following the link. So any code after:

```
if(isset($submit)) {
```

Will not fire.

Comment: huh? why not? the if(isset($submit)) { is for the submit button of the search form. The link ($sendmessage) is the one who is not responding.

Comment: There are two if(isset($submit)) { lines. The first of which line ~23 seems to encompass the rest of the code.

Comment: Hello. The other isset($submit) is for the submit button inside of the  messaging table that is not appearing after I click the link, so I think it is not the reason.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a lot wrong with this form.  First off, you forgot a `<tr>` and `<td>` after your `<table>` tag.

```
echo "<center><form name = 'searching' method='POST' action='cpanel.php?manage=".$useraccounts."&rcad=".$viewcustomer."'><table border = 1><tr><td colspan='10'>";
    echo "<select name = 'filter'>";
    echo "<option value ='username'>Username</option>";
    echo "<option value ='username'>Username</option>";
    echo "</select>";
    echo "  <input name='search' type='text' >   "; 
    echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Search'> ";
    echo "<input type='submit' name='back' value='Back'><br><br>";
    echo "</td></tr>";
```

Alternatively you could move the opening `<table>` tag below the `<select>` tag.

After you fix that, try moving the logic where you insert the values into mailtbl_admin outside of the loop.  I'm guessing you're only going to want to send the message to one user, so it only makes sense to move it out of the loop.

Comment: Alternatively you could move the opening <table> tag below the <select> tag. -> I think this is not an issue since it is inside the form.

Comment: I'm guessing you're only going to want to send the message to one user, so it only makes sense to move it out of the loop. -> EXACTLY! but if i move it out of the loop, it will still have the same results

Comment: Well your logic is just flawed with the whole structure of this code.  It's generally frowned upon to combine programming logic (such as form submissions) with the layout.  Moving out all of this will most likely help you debug.  Also, like was stated in the comments, `$sendmessage` will always trigger since you're initializing it a couple lines about the code.  Also, the second `isset($submit)` will always be true because that is nested inside of another `isset($submit)` block.